# How can I use integer division (//) to access the middle rows and columns in numpy python

Tags: python, numpy

Print "+"
Description
Given a single positive odd integer 'n' greater than 2, create a NumPy array of size (n x n) with all zeros and ones such that the ones make a shape like '+'. The lines of the plus must be present at the middle row and column.

Hint: Start by creating a (n x n) array with all zeroes using the np.zeros() function and then fill in the ones at the appropriate indices. Use integer division (//) to access the middle rows and columns

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your homework for you. Please show what you've tried so far and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

index for middle row: n//2
index for middle column: n//2

```py
import numpy as np

def f(n):
    if n<3:
        print('Argument must greater  or equal 3 !')
        return
    middle = n//2
    array = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.uint)
    array[middle] = 1
    array[:, middle] = 1
    print(array)
```